# Would a right triangle with bases $a=i$ and $b=1$ have hypotenuse $c=0$?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, triangles

Suppose we have a right angle triangle with $a$ and $b$ as bases and $c$ as the hypotenuse, letting
$$a=i$$$$b=1$$
Wouldn't the hypotenuse then be$$i^2+1=0$$
I am finding it hard to understand how this may be possible since the hypotenuse by definition is the longest side of a right angled triangle, how could this be, perhaps this exists for a non euclidean geometry?

Comment: What does even $a=i$ mean?

Comment: The base $$a=-1^{1/2}$$

Comment: What I wanted to point out is how do you define a triangle wirh base $i$?

Comment: Fun fact: Consider a "right-corner tetrahedron" $OPQR$ with edges $p:=|OP|$, $q:=|OQ|$, $r:=|OR|$ meeting at right corner $O$. (Eg, put $O$ at the origin, and $P$, $Q$, $R$ at $(p,0,0)$, $(0,q,0)$, $(0,0,r)$.) Then an area-based Pythagorean relation holds: $$|\triangle OQR|^2+|\triangle POR|^2+|\triangle PQO|^2=|\triangle PQR|^2$$ Re-writing the left in terms of $a:=|QR|$, $b:=|RP|$, $c:=|PQ|$ gives Heron's formula for $|\triangle PQR|$ in terms of its sides. Nifty! But this only works for non-obtuse $\triangle PQR$ ... unless we allow one of $p$, $q$, $r$ to be *imaginary*. (continued)

Comment: (continuing) See, for instance, the ["Heron's Formula for Tetrahedra" entry](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath226/kmath226.htm) of Kevin Brown's MathPages. (The entire entry is interesting, but the above is discussed in the first part.)... So, "imaginary lengths" actually have their uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$i$ is an imaginary number $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Such a right triangle with legs $a=i, \ b=1$ doesn't exist.

because side of right triangle can't be imaginary i.e. $a\ne i$

all the sides of an existing triangle must be positive real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

As Shiva Venkata said, a triangle with imaginary sides does not exist, *normally*. Within Euclidean space this makes sense. However, if we bend our notions of distance to accomodate alternative geometries, such as the [Lorenzian/Minkowski geometry](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Minkowski_space) used in the special theory of relativity, then the question makes sense.

Suppose you're sitting a meter apart from your friend Marie. Creating a [spacetime diagram](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Spacetime_diagram) from your reference frame, at an arbitrary starting point $t=0$ you're at the origin and she's at $(ct,x)=(0,1)$. At this moment you decide to take a picture with the flash on, sending a cascade of photons that hit Marie's eyes after $1/c$ seconds. Hence, the flash illuminates her face at the event $(ct,x)=(1,1)$.

So we have three events:

- A: The flash at $(0,0)$
- B: An unilluminated Maria at $(0, 1)$
- C: An illuminated future Maria at $(1,1)$

Let's compute the [spacetime interval](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Spacetime#/Spacetime_interval), i.e. distance squared, between them. For points $P,Q$ this is

$$\ell^2_{PQ} = -(P_t - Q_t)^2 + (P_x - Q_x)^2$$

- $\ell^2_{AB} = -(A_t - B_t)^2 + (A_x - B_x)^2 = -(0)^2+(1)^2 = 1$
- $\ell^2_{BC} = -(1)^2+(0)^2 = -1$
- $\ell^2_{CA} = -(1)^2+(1)^2 = 0$

This corresponds to the physically significant notion that A & B are spacelike-seprated, B & C timelike, and A & C lightlike. Taking the square-roots provides you with the actual distances between points, and therefore the lengths of the segments they define:

- $\ell_{AB} = 1$
- $\ell_{BC} = i$
- $\ell_{CA} = 0$

If we put all the events on a spacetime diagram, they would indeed form a triangle! In fact, they form a right-triangle with respect to this geometry, as  $\bar{AB}$ and $\bar{BC}$ are actually still orthogonal in this non-Euclidean setting. With these segments serving as the legs, the segment $\bar{CA}$ is the hypotenuse, which does indeed have length zero.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exist, because a triangle must be defined as having side lengths of positive real numbers (even $-1$ wouldn't count, let alone imaginary numbers).

If you are talking about the triangle formed by $0\leq x\leq 1$, and $0\leq y \leq i$ on the Argand Diagram, that has side lengths of $1$ and hypotenuse $\sqrt 2$